# How do I turn off GDB TUI?

Tags: gdb

I have this GDB TUI/layout on. How do I return to the default GDB view?

I can't just restart GDB, because I have important backtrace on my hand and as long as I have these extra windows I can't scroll well on the basic view.

Answer (score 25):

You can enter / leave the TUI mode with one of this combinations:

- C-x C-a
- C-x a
- C-x A

This is typically (no need to lift the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: But see http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15163, which is a fun gotcha for the vi-inclined.

Comment: @RhysUlerich thanks! I think that was also mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953720/cannot-leave-tui-mode-with-ctrl-x-a-nor-see-program-output-in-tui-mode , and there is likely to be a workaround soon: http://superuser.com/a/927728/128124

Answer (score 10):

Because of the bug [Ulerich mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/180512/how-to-turn-off-gdb-tui#comment674829_238203) which breaks the mappings if you have `vi` mode in your `.inputrc`, I have requested a workaround [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2015-06/msg00009.html) and Andrew Burgess replied that he had [just submitted](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2015-05/msg00559.html) a well received patch to add:

```
tui enable
tui disable
```

So in future versions we should have commands as an alternative to the shortcuts.

I have later tested this on GDB 8.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked perfectly.

But then I saw the light and moved from TUI to [GDB Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115540/gdb-split-view-with-code/51301717#51301717) which is simply more powerful and less buggy.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409540/how-to-close-layout-src-windows-in-gdb